Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible
estoy agregando a mi app el sdk de mercado pago y al hacerlo me tira el siguiente error. No se que podria ser y ya probe de todo.
Este es el error que me tira:

Este es mi build.gradle:



Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
